# Is there a way to fix my Date Slider in Plotly so that it Generates an Animation Frame for each day?

Tags: python, plotly

Here's my data and visualization thus far:

```py
import pandas as pd 
import plotly.express as px
  
# intialise data of lists. 
data = {'Subreddit':["90DayFiance","Anarchism","Animemes","AskALiberal",
                "AskALiberal","AskReddit","AskReddit","AskReddit","AskReddit","AskTeenGirls","CatastrophicFailure",
                "Conservative","Deji","DhGateReps","DontFundMe","Drama","Drizzy","DuggarsSnark",
                "Eminem","Enough_Sanders_Spam","Enough_Sanders_Spam","Enough_Sanders_Spam","Enough_Sanders_Spam",
                "FixedPoliticalMemes"], 
        'Date':["2020-07-08 00:00:00-04:00","2020-07-08 00:00:00-04:00","2020-07-08 00:00:00-04:00",
               "2020-07-09 00:00:00-04:00","2020-07-09 00:00:00-04:00","2020-07-09 00:00:00-04:00",
               "2020-07-09 00:00:00-04:00","2020-07-04 00:00:00-04:00","2020-07-04 00:00:00-04:00",
               "2020-07-04 00:00:00-04:00","2020-07-04 00:00:00-04:00","2020-07-10 00:00:00-04:00",
               "2020-07-10 00:00:00-04:00","2020-07-10 00:00:00-04:00","2020-07-10 00:00:00-04:00",
               "2020-07-10 00:00:00-04:00","2020-07-10 00:00:00-04:00","2020-07-18 00:00:00-04:00",
               "2020-07-18 00:00:00-04:00","2020-07-18 00:00:00-04:00","2020-07-09 00:00:00-04:00",
               "2020-07-09 00:00:00-04:00","2020-07-08 00:00:00-04:00","2020-07-10 00:00:00-04:00"],
       'Count':["3","2","2","2","2","3","5","6","12","7","2","7","4","3","5","3","5","15","5","4","2","3","5",'5'],
       'Day':["08", "08", "08", "09", "09", "09", "09", "04", "04", "04", "04", "10", "10", "10", "10",
              "10", "10", "18", "18", "18", "09", "09", "08", "10"]} 
  
# Create DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 



fig = px.bar(df,
             x="Subreddit",
             y="Count",
             animation_frame="Day",
             animation_group="Subreddit", 
             range_y=[0, 50])

fig.show()
```

Is there a way to make the slider responsive to the date? As of now, I just have the day as a dummy to represent the day, but obviously I'd rather slide from earlier to later in time and show the frequency per Subreddit for each day.

Comment: Do you mind to show us a link with an example? I don't think I got what are you looking for.

Comment: Something like the chart at the bottom of this link https://plotly.com/python/v3/gapminder-example/

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://plotly.com/python/v3/gapminder-example/#plot-animation)?

Comment: @rpanai yes, exactly

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because the time series data is not sorted.
In case you're wondering, I converted the date column to date format and then updated it with date only information before sorting it.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Day'] = df['Date'].dt.day
df.sort_values('Day', ascending=True, ignore_index=True, inplace=True)

import plotly.express as px
  
fig = px.bar(df,
             x="Subreddit",
             y="Count",
             animation_frame="Day",
             animation_group="Subreddit", 
             range_y=[0, 50])

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Right, but my only issue here is what happens if the date goes into the next month, so we have 25,26,28,30,01,02. We would want 01 and 02 to be at the end.

Comment: I think it should be shown in 'mm-dd'. That's what a timeline is.